# Convertir horas del dia actual al anterior en bigquery

Tags: sql

estoy intentando calcular la cantidad de envios procesados por día de cada turno, el problema es que el turno noche atraviesa 2 días (comienza a las 22 de la noche y termina a las 06 del dia siguiente) como podria hacer para que las 06 horas de la madrugada cuenten para la fecha del día anterior? muchas gracias! [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pasa la consulta  código por favor.

Comment: No uses imágenes por favor. Usa texto para el código y para los datos. Y danos un ejemplo de data de la tabla y el resultado deseado para ese data. Y no entiendo como relata la tabla y el parte de código que nos estás mostrando a tu pregunta. ¿Porque adicionas una hora? ¿Porque separas fecha y hora? Además, hablas de turnos (noche = 22:00 - 06:00), y dices que quieres la cantidad de envíos procesados por día de cada turno. Entonces, ¿qué es un envío procesado?, y ¿qué turnos hay?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT                          
EXTRACT (HOUR FROM (DATETIME_ADD(TMS.ORDER.OUTBOUND.INCLUDED_AT,INTERVAL 1 HOUR))) AS FECHA,                            
COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS PROCESADO,                            
FROM meli-bi-data.SHIPPING_BI.BT_SHP_MT_TMS_ORDERS AS TMS                           
WHERE LOGISTIC_CENTER_ID = "ARBA01"                         
AND DATE(ORDER_DATE_CREATED) >= CURRENT_DATE("America/Buenos_Aires")-21                         
AND EXTRACT (HOUR FROM DATETIME_ADD(TMS.ORDER.OUTBOUND.INCLUDED_AT,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) BETWEEN 14 AND 21                          
AND DATE (DATETIME_ADD(TMS.ORDER.OUTBOUND.INCLUDED_AT,INTERVAL 1 HOUR)) = CURRENT_DATE("America/Buenos_Aires")-1                            
AND SUBSTR(TMS.ORDER.OUTBOUND.POSITION,0,1) = "8"                           
GROUP BY 1                          
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

Comment: Por favor, detalle su respuesta, le ayudará más.

Comment: Puedes usar el botón `{}` en el editor para formatear tu código. Y por favor nunca des respuestas de código sólo; siempre explica que hace to código y como eso resuelve el problema.

Comment: Y, ¿se supone que eso es una respuesta? ¿O estás tratando de dar más informaciones relacionadas con tu pregunta? En este caso no lo escribas coma respuesta, por favor, pero [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/616393/edit) tu pregunta.

Comment: Al respecto al estilo de tu código: Es difícil leer código SQL con todo en mayúsculas. Es mejor poner todo en minúsculas o usar mayúsculas para las palabras claves de SQL y minúsculas para los nombres.

Answer (score 0):

De las 6:00 hasta las 23:59 el fecha es lo que quieres, de las 0:00 hasta las 5:59 debe contar como la fecha anterior. Entonces mira la hora: 6-23 = okay, 0-5 = día anterior. Para el turno es probablemente bastante tambíén mirar la hora.

Aquí esta la consulta. Puedes arreglarla, si la nececitas un poco diferente.

```
WITH fechas_corrigidas AS
(
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM included_at) IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN
      DATE_SUB(DATE(included_at), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ELSE
      DATE(included_at)
    END AS fecha,
    CASE WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM included_at) IN (6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13) THEN
      'mañana'
    WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM included_at) IN (14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21) THEN
      'tarde'
    WHEN EXTRACT(HOUR FROM included_at) IN (22,23,0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN
      'noche'
    END AS turno
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT fecha, turno, COUNT(*)
FROM fechas_corrigidas
GROUP BY fecha, turno
ORDER BY fecha, turno;
```